# how to iterate the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate the list over 500+ times.

right now I am using by single method:

```py
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10 = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] 

     for x in range [3,500]:
        col+str(x) = []
```

the "col" should be constant and iteration should be over 500 times

Comment: You need a list of lists: `[[], [], [], [], ...]`

Comment: it's really not necessary to create 497 `col` variables. Use a different data structure :)

Comment: use dict or list comprehension: `columns = {i:[] for i in range(3,500)}` or `columns = [[] for i in range(3,500)]`.

Comment: If you really need to do this (which you shouldn't), you can do for x in range(500): exec("col" + str(x) + "=[]")

Comment: thank you for the help, but unfortunately again stuck in looping :(

Answer (score 4):

just use a list (of lists):

```py
cols = []
for x in range(500):
    cols.append([])
```

then you can access each individual col by `cols[42]` (or any other index...)

Comment: Do it in one line: cols = [[] for x in range(500)]

Comment: You can just do `cols = [[]]*500`.

Comment: @Acccumulation no no, see this: https://ideone.com/YkZt89